# Sequelize user.increment("somethings") do not update the value

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, discord, discord.js

when I try to **increment** something with sequelize it **doesn't return** me the **updated value** (incremented) and to get that I **need** to **reuse** `findOne` method.

Looking in the sequelize doc [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-increment) in the increment section you can read this:

> The updated instance will be returned by default in Postgres. However,
> in other dialects, you will need to do a reload to get the new values.

Is ther any way to "fix" it without using this "workaround" ( recalling `findOne` )?

```
 const user = await Tags.findOne({
    where: { id: ID },
 });      

await user.increment("rank");
    
 const user1 = await Tags.findOne({
    where: { id: ID },
 });
```